# PHP JSON Return to Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

Iv read a lot of search results regarding how to deal with a JSON array that is returned from an Ajax function, but none seem to fit my problem.

Explain:
I am effectively searching through a database in a tree like structure to return *all* of the child elements of a given element. There may be from 1 to many hundreds of results. All of this grunt work is done in PHP, which then returns a JSON array containing the results, however, I cant seem to work out how to iterate over the result, which looks like this:

```
{ 
  "Kaz1Kid43343757245": {
    "kaz1KidKid24572649":[],
    "kaz1KidKid24572649Back":[]
  },
  "Kaz1Kid43343757245Back":[]
}
```

Note that each of the items needs to be returned as an individual ID, but if I try

```
$.each(obj, function(key, val)
{
    //doing stuff with each item
});
```

I only get two of the results (Kaz1Kid43343757245 and Kaz1Kid43343757245Back) in the keys while the val's show nothing at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

MVK

Comment: You really would have made this easier on us if you'd changed those strings to something we could distinguish at a glance.

Comment: Okay, but thats the way the data comes back and all of the data I need is there, I just cant seem to get at it.

Comment: Scott, sorry yes, thats the internal ID's - didn't think to change them - Iv been looking at them all day!

Comment: I have edited your question just to show you what you get from the server-side. ) Yes, it's an object with two keys you named; values are object (with two keys) for the first one and an empty array for the second.

Comment: So the question now is what you want to get as a _final_ result. That, in turn, might suggest a better way of parsing what you get from PHP script.

Comment: As a final result, idealy, Id have a normal javascript array containing one id as each element, but it makes no real difference if its an object, just so long as I can iterate over it easily.

Comment: Ok, but are `Kaz1Kid43343757245` and `Kaz1Kid43343757245Back` really two different ids? And how many levels may the resulting JSON tree contain - just two, as in your example, or infinite? )

Comment: Yes both are unique keys, related, but unique. As for the number of levels, theoretically its infinite, so the number of results will vary greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a recursive function, which will loop down into objects it encounters or add the key/value to a new, flat object:

```
function flatten(obj) {
    var result = {};

    function list(node) {
        $.each(node, function(key, val){
            if (jQuery.isPlainObject(val)) {
                list(val);
            } else {
                result[key] = val;
            }
        });
    }

    list(obj);
    return result;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nssvk/

Or a tiny bit fancier way to run the first call:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nssvk/1/

Which gives:

```
{
    "Kaz1Kid43343757245Back" : []
    "kaz1KidKid24572649"     : []
    "kaz1KidKid24572649Back" : []
}
```

Question is, what do you want to do with the "flattened away" keys such as `Kaz1Kid43343757245` in your example object?

Comment: Thanks Jared, but that only returns *three* of the ID's! I most definitely need all of them! The keys are all related to documents stored in the database and this group are the result of a recursive search to find all of the children of another element. What happens to them next is up to the user but I need to be able to iterate over the results and get all items (of which there may be many - this is only a tiny example).

Comment: Look at the last sentence in my answer - "How do you want to treat the flattened keys"? This was a question I had, how did you want to deal with it. So when you say "get all items", what does that mean?

Comment: For instance, if you wanted to flatten and promote recursively, look at the object you would get here: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nssvk/2/ It shouldn't be hard to tailor that to what you need in practice if all you need is to introspect.

Comment: Ah, sorry, early morning - not enough coffee yet! *"How do you want to treat the flattened keys"* - I want to be able to loop through the results an perform an operation on each item in turn. Sorry, but I don't understand introspection at all!

Comment: I didn't use introspection correctly; it's really just recursion. All I've done is wrap the `$.each()` you had in a function so it can call itself when it comes across a `val` that is needing to be "explored". So, go through each object property, and if the value of the object property is an object, send that value (really, an object) to the `list(obj)` function, which then works through that object. So it just steps into the objects it encounters and unzips them as it goes, until it travels back up to the root object and completes.

Comment: I kind of see what you have done, but why does it only return three of the four items, and, more importantly I cant see how to return the fourth.

Comment: Ok, so try this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/gvmQd/1 And this shows "work" on storing all four: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nssvk/2/.

Comment: Now I'm completely confused! What is is that I should be seeing in that fiddle?

Comment: That if a thing (your current `val` in the iteration) is a things (pluralized), go do what you did with the original things on that thing. It's a really simple pattern, but you kinda gotta look at it sideways.

Comment: Yes, okay, a recursive loop - if the item has children, check each child for children ..... but this is where I came in - I have a result but I am unable to perform this recursion so that I can iterate through each item - I could get two of the results, and your code can get three of them, but there are four results, and I cant work out how to get to that fourth result!

Comment: It's right there. I get it in this fiddle, right after I run the `if` check: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nssvk/2/

Comment: I'm logging what's happening in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nssvk/4/

Comment: Thats excellent Jared, thanks - I simply could not see how removing that 'else' would return the final item! very many thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Iv marked this is a correct answer, but I cant vote it up for you because I have too little experience, sorry, and thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't worry about the vote, it's all good.

Answer (score 2):

You need to recurse into the array. Your code only looks at the first level, but as you say yourself: it's a tree structure. So if an element is an array, you need to go in and get your values out again, And if those are arrays, you need to …

Comment: You need to ... ? Reminds me of Monty Python Holy Grail's castle. )

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite the Object literal with proper indentation:

```
{
  "Kaz1Kid43343757245": {
    "kaz1KidKid24572649": [],
    "kaz1KidKid24572649Back": []
  },
  "Kaz1Kid43343757245Back": []
}
```

I think it's obvious now why the loop iterates only over two properties. You will need to restructure the generated JSON.